# $a-b$ and $b+c$ are known. Can $ab$ be found?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

a, b and c are unknowns and I have two equations: $a-b=x_1$ and $b+c=x_2$. Is there a way to obtain explicit solution to $ab$ or $abc$ or any other multiplication of the unknowns?

Any approximations are welcome. I am not looking for an exact solution.

Edit: please note that I am not looking for solutions for $a$, $b$ or $c$, but for $ab$ or $bc$ or any other combination.

Comment: Knowing $b+c$ gives you no information about $ab$.

Comment: $ab$ is approximately zero--but this may not be a very good approximation.

Comment: Just to convince yourself that this is not enough information, add some conditions.  Add the constraint $a=c$, for instance.  Now try $b=c$.  Or $a=c+3$ or, really, whatever.  Whichever you pick you should easily be able to solve for $a,b$ but of course your solution will depend on which extra constraint you chose.

Comment: I don't want solution for a or b or c. I am looking for (ab) or variable like that.

Comment: it will work if $ b>>c$  we can  take approximation $b=x_2$

Comment: @user2574723 I think you missed lulu's point entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible, because $ab$ is not uniquely determined by this system.

The general solution of the system is
$$a = t, \quad b = t - x_1, \quad c = x_1 + x_2 - t$$
where $t$ is any real number.  Then $ab = t^2 - tx_1$, and you can see that by varying $t$, this may take different values.

Explicitly, suppose $x_1 = x_2 = 0$, so the system is $a-b=0$ and $b+c=0$.  Then one solution is $a=2, b=2, c=-2$, in which case $ab=4$.  Another solution is $a=3, b=3, c=-3$ in which case $ab = 9$.  So the system of equations does not give you enough information to tell whether $ab$ is $4$ or $9$ or some other value.

One thing you can say: by completing the square, we have 
$$ab = \left(t - \frac{1}{2}x_1\right)^2 - \frac{1}{4} x_1^2 \ge -\frac{1}{4} x_1^2$$
so at least you have a lower bound for $ab$.

Comment: Thanks! Such a simple analysis!